# CRM 2011, REST, OData and Security Roles

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

Is there any special security privileges that i need to give my users so that they can run some custom code? I have a javascript library that is triggered on a button click that then gets all of the selected items in a subgrid. When I get all of the check-boxed items I then feed that into an update operation and upload the string if items (in the form of GUIDs) into a Single Line Textbox field on my entity. Once that field is updated they will trigger a dialog which consumes the textbox field and does some more work on it.

The problem is that nothing happens. I solved one issue once I figured out that the user needs Organizational write access to the entity, but now I see another exception "...is missing prvReadWorkflow privilege" does that mean these users need Read Access on Organizational workflows?

Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explaination for why you require read access to workflows for this update operation, but this [microsoft CRM forum post](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/crm/thread/e96c34fa-bb17-418b-8a15-b028f231f0f2) appears to be about the same issue you are having.

Tanguy suggests you add read access to processes for the affected user.